# DelegateTask.setAssignee not setting claim time

Tags: activiti

In a listener, I am using delegateTask.setAssignee
but it doesn't set claim_time_ field in the act_ru_task table.

Is it correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is expected. the `claim_time` in `act_ru_task` only gets updated if a user "claims" the task which is under a candidate group or users assignment. To update this field you need to claim the task using `taskService.claimTask(taskId, userId)`.

`delegateTask.setAssignee(userId)` is equivalent to setting an assignee in process model.